# Kubernetes - How to get the CPU/Memory usage of Pods/Nodes without Metric Server

Tags: kubectl

I was trying out the CKA test on killer.sh where i came across this question to get the resource utilization of nodes and pods and sort them by specific order but the metric server is not preset on cluster.

so now `kubectl top` can't be used. Anyone know any commands that can be used to get these details.

thanks.

Comment: You can't do this without something like metric server or prometheus to provide the metrics.